# Graphic Spark User Interface :4040 in SSH VM

Tags: azure, apache-spark

I am executing Spark in cluster mode in 2 Azure VMs. As usual, I'm connected to these machines through SSH and I can access to http://localhost:4040 through a command line browser and "see" job progress.

Since command line browsers are really poor, I'd like to see the classical Web User Interface offered by Spark, in order to appreciate the Graphical details. Is there a solution to reach this goal?

Comment: Would it be feasible to open the 4040 port and just connect from your browser locally to the Web UI on the remote machine?

Comment: great! following these [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal) I managed to open the 4040 port in the VM and connect to the Spark Jobs monitoring. Postala come risposta che te l'accetto (magari fai anche riferimento al link che ho citato, può essere utile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the most straightforward way to go is to open port 4040 and just connect from your browser locally to the Web UI on the remote machine.

Be advised, of course, that you may want to pay extra-attention to how the node is secured once it's open for connection from the external world.

As mentioned in a comment, opening ports on Azure is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal).

Answer (score 2):

You might try to run a modern browser via ssh with [x11 forwarding](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3515/how-do-i-launch-a-remote-firefox-window-via-ssh). Use the [compression option](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-speed-up-x11-forwarding-in-ssh.html) to speed up the experience.

Comment: I had a `Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays` that I resolved through [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802877/x11-errors-over-ssh), but after that it "worked", the only problem is that it is incredibly slow, impossible to use it (sometime I have lags in my local laptop), any idea of this behavior? I can't neither access to http://localhost:4040

Comment: You might try a to install a light browser such luakit instead of firefox